# CodeAcademy Class Average

Tags: python

I have an error on line 28 saying:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total referenced before assignment.
```

However total is referenced above line 28 on line 24. I don't understand what's going on.  The code I'm trying to write is to take the average of each students' test, quizzes and homework scores.

Thanks for your help.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
def average(some):
    return sum(some)/len(some)

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

total = 0

def get_class_average(students):
    for student in students:
        total += get_class_average(students)
    return float(total) / len(students)

print get_class_average(students)
```

Comment: Note that the `UnboundLocalError` is only one of the errors you will get.  You also will get a `RuntimeError` because you have a never ending recursive loop in `get_class_average`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark `total` as a global if you are to assign to it in your function:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    global total
    for student in students:
        total += get_class_average(students)
    return float(total) / len(students)
```

By assigning to a given variable, you are marking it as a local name unless you explicitly mark it as a global.

You may want to move `total` *into* the function instead of making it a global:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    total = 0
    for student in students:
        total += get_class_average(students)
    return float(total) / len(students)
```

You don't appear to be using it elsewhere in your code, so making it a global is overkill here.

Your next problem is that you are calling `get_class_average()` recursively; the function is calling *itself*, passing in the *exact same arguments*. The function will never return. I suspect you meant to call the `average()` function instead, passing in a specific list for each student, like the `homework` key, or `quizzes` or `tests`:

```
def get_class_average(students, key):
    total = 0
    for student in students:
        total += average(student[key])
    return float(total) / len(students)

homework_average = get_class_average(students, 'homework']
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error on line 29 with regards to indentation.

Comment: @RobB.: Did you mix tabs and spaces perhaps? Make sure your indentation matches. The extra line (either `total = 0` or `global total` doesn't change the indentation of the other lines.

Comment: Isn't `get_class_average` just going to keep calling itself?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters,
Thanks for the input things are becoming clearer.

But how would I make this code giving me averages for Llyod's, Tyler's and Alice's test scores separately?

Comment: @RobB.: You could store the `average` out in a loop variable, then print out `student['name']` and the result of `average(student[key])` instead (or in addition to) calculating the class total.